# Memory corruption when using boost::shared_ptr in a multithreaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, boost

*** glibc detected *** malloc(): memory corruption (fast): ***

This is the error I get when, in a multithreaded environment, I execute this portion of code:

```
/// Some declarations
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Object> ObjectPtr;

ObjectPtr getObject()
{
    return ObjectPtr(new Object);
}

/// What is actually executed in a thread
void executeWork()
{
    ...
    ObjectPtr object = getObject(); /* <--- Memory corruption here! */
    ...
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: post the `Object` class source code

Comment: Can you reproduce the error under valgrind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this helps your specific problem, but it is sometimes desirable to use `make_shared` and avoid the `new`.

so:

```
return boost::make_shared<Object>(/* any arguments to constructor here */);
```

Additionally, you could try `std::shared_ptr` instead of `boost::shared_ptr`. They're probably exactly the same, but maybe not? To use it via TR1, I believe you `#include <tr1/memory>`. I usually just use it via C++0x, in which case it's `#include <memory>` and add `-std=c++0x` to your g++ flags.

Comment: I had a similar problem and this helped me. I wish I knew why though.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely to be a problem with Object.  What happens if you change Object to int?

Comment: It's still buggy if I change Object to int!